# Characteristic polynomial of a unitary matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given a matrix a unitary $A$ $\in$ $M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{R})$, how does one show that its characteristic polynomial $\triangle_A(t)$ satisfies the following:

$t^n \triangle_A(1/t) = \pm \triangle_A(t)$.

I see that the characteristic polynomial is essentially symmetric (or anti-symmetric). I have shown that the determinant of a unitary matrix are $\pm 1$ and that its eigenvalues all have modulus 1. I feel that there is a connection between these properties and the structure of its characteristic polynomial.

If we are dealing with real numbers, it could happen that all of the eigenvalues are either 1 or -1. Then, using the binomial theorem, we would have $\triangle_A(t)= (t \pm 1)^n$, and we would obtain a symmetric or anti-symmetric polynomial.

However, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

A unitary matrix with real entries satisfies $A^TA=I$, where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. By definition, the characteristic polynomial $p_A(t)=\det(tI-A)$, hence
$$ t^np_A(1/t)=t^n\det((1/t)I-A)=\det(I-tA)=\det(A^TA-tA)$$
$$=\det(A^T-tI)\det(A)=(-1)^n\det((tI-A)^T)\det(A)=(-1)^n\det(tI-A)\det(A)$$
$$ =(-1)^n\det(A)p_A(t) $$

Finally, $\det(A)=\pm 1$ since $A^TA=I$, so we get the desired result.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you!